# Problems with accessing functions data after an upgrade from ADS 2019.1.1 to ADS 2020.0.1RC

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Have anyone else experienced issues after an upgrade from ADS 2019.1.1 to ADS 2020.0.1RC with the codecoverage rest API described here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/code%20coverage/get%20build%20code%20coverage?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

On my site all the functions data disappeared even though the Flags value is set to 7. For each item the functions part of the json looks like this: "functions":[]

When I set it to 2 (supposedly just the functions data) it gets even worse as the result is:
{"value":[{"configuration":{"id":305570,"uri":"vstfs:///Build/Build/399350","flavor":"","platform":"","project":{}},"state":"0","lastError":"","modules":[],"codeCoverageFileUrl":"{myServerAddress}/_apis/testresults/codecoverage/download/478471?filePath=%2FBuildCoverage%2F20210215.3...305570.coverage"}],"count":1}

Just a json with a link to a coverage file...

Comment: Flags are additive. Expected Values are 1 for Modules, 2 for Functions, 4 for BlockData. There is no 7. How's the result you got in ADS 2019.1.1? Please check whether you installed the latest patch for ADS 2020.0.1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Flags are additive indeed, but doesn't it mean that I should pick 1 + 2 + 4 = 7 when I want to receive Modules, Functions and BlockData?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Which response did you get in ADS 2019.1.1?